# Insert image as background in multirow in a table

Tags: tables, graphics, multirow, backgrounds

I would like to insert an image as background for a `multirow` in a table. It would be great to have something like this

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{array,colortbl,multirow,multicol,booktabs,ctable} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1cm} X p{70pt}
\multirow{2}{*}{\includegraphics[some options]{image}}&stuff&\\
&&stuff
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what is wanted ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{array,colortbl,multirow,multicol,booktabs,ctable} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mwe} % for dummy picture

\newcommand{\mystrut}{\rule{0pt}{3.5cm}} % the height may be adjusted 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c m{5cm} X p{70pt}}
1&\multirow{2}{=}{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}}&stuff&\\
2&&stuff\\
3\mystrut&stuff&stuff % the third line height is set = 3.5cm
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I altready tried this but unfortunately the image height is not automatically adjusted to the height of the multirow. I was indeed looking for an option that fits the height of the image to the multirow.

Comment: @student. To my knowledge there is no option in `\multirow` that allows the height row  to  fit the content . I have updated my answer with a workaround adapted from a solution given in the *multirow* package manual.